# How can I send more than 5 emails per hour?

Tags: 9, emails

Drupal doesn't allow to send more than 5 emails per hour from a contact form.

Can this value of 5 be changed somewhere? I need to change it for testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [stated in the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/contact/overview#s-controlling-repeat-submission-blocking-flood-control):

> There are hard-coded limits to how frequently contact forms can be
> submitted. In Drupal 8, a special drush command provides a way to
> configure flood control behavior: drush cedit contact.settings This
> lets you change the limit and time limit after which the flood
> restriction resets.
>
> You can view the default/current settings with:
>
> `drush config-get contact.settings`

When you execute `drush cedit contact.settings`, a text editor will appear (the details depend on your settings).

It will look something like this:

```
default_config_hash: abcdefg
langcode: en
default_form: feedback
flood:
  limit: 5
  interval: 3600
user_default_enabled: true
```

Change `limit` under `flood` to be the number of attempts you want per hour (defaults to `5`).

You can also change `interval` to adjust the number of seconds that the limit is imposed for (by default, `3600` seconds = 1 hour).

Comment: The command allows me to view details but how to do I change?

Comment: @markus It could be clearer, but it says it right there in the post: `drush cedit contact.settings`.

Comment: Sorry I am in a loss, how do you suggest to edit?

Comment: @markus Updated with an example.

Comment: Crap, that requires me to use Vim (or something like Vim) which I don't know how to use. I need to use `nano`.

Comment: Perhaps I can edit from GUI somehow?

Comment: @markus Please check the docs; you can easily set the editor to whatever you want: https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/config_edit/

Comment: In UI you can copy the original config from admin/config/development/configuration/single/export and paste the changed config to admin/config/development/configuration/single/import.

Comment: I have tried `vendor/bin/drush cedit contact.settings --editor[=nano]` but that doesn't work. I don't know how else to understand the docs.

Comment: `vendor/bin/drush cedit contact.settings --editor[nano]` also didn't work.

Comment: @markus – You can also simply export config, edit `contact.settings.yml` manually, and import config again.

Comment: Brackets in command examples are for demonstration, so it is `vendor/bin/drush cedit contact.settings --editor=nano`.